# Why are not all files compressed and how to improve the solution

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, tar, pipe

I have a folder with about 20K files. The files are named according to the pattern `xy_{\d1,5}_{\d4}\.abc`, e.g `xy_12345_1234.abc`. I wanted to compress the first 10K of them using this command:

`ls | sort -n -k1.4,1.9 | head -n10000 | xargs tar -czf xy_0_10000.tar.gz`

however the resulting file had only about 2K files inside.

`ls | sort -n -k1.4,1.9 | head -n10000 | wc -l` however returns 10000, as expected.

It seems to me that I am misunderstanding something basic here...

I am using zsh 5.0.2 on Linux Mint 17.1, GNU tar 1.27.1

*EDIT:*

forking as suggested by @Archemar sounds very plausible, with the latest fork overwriting the resulting file - the file contains the 'tail' of the files - *7773* to *9999*.

result of `xargs --show-limit`: 

`Your environment variables take up 3973 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 2091131
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2087158
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072`

replacing `-c` with `-r` or `-u` did not work in my case. The error message was `tar: Cannot update compressed archives`

using both `-r` and `-u` is invalid and fails with `tar: You may not specify more than one '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or  '--test-label' option`

replacing `-c` with `-a` seems to be invalid as well and fails with the same `tar: You must specify one of the '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or '--test-label' options` though I dont recognize the issue `azf` and `Acdtrux` seem disjunct to me.

*EDIT 2:*

-T looks like a good way, I have also found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597875/how-can-i-build-a-tar-from-stdin).

However when I try

`ls | sort -n -k1.4,1.9 | head -n10000 | tar -czf xy_0_10000.tar.gz -T -` i get
`tar: option requires an argument -- 'T'`

well, perhaps the filenames dont reach tar? But it looks like they, do because when I execute

`ls | sort -n -k1.4,1.9 | head -n10000 | tar --null -czf xy_0_10000.tar.gz -T -` i get
`tar: xy_0_.ab\nxy_1_...<the rest of filenames separated by literal \n>...998.ab
Cannot stat: File name too long`

So why is tar not seeing the filenames?

Comment: and if you try a instead of c, in the tar command?

Comment: Relevant: [Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: OP's file do not have tricky names.

Comment: @8bittree - well as a general advice for robust shell scripts, yes. but what do you suggest instead for working with lists of files with the regular one-off oneliners?

Comment: @Archemar True, but future people coming here for help might have tricky file names, and the OP may do something similar in the future with tricky file names. Might as well learn the safe way now.

Comment: @kostja I'd use [`find`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind), which has a `-print0` option to use a null byte as the delimiter instead of a newline. `sort` can handle that with the `-z` flag. `head`, unfortunately does not handle understand null byte delimiters, but [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75206) has a solution using `tr` to swap `\n` and `\0` before and after `head`. `tar` has `--null -T -` to read null delimited file names from `stdin`.

Comment: @8bittree - cool, this works as well :) Probably I will ignore your (still valid and reasonable) advice for most of what I do on the command line because I mostly do simple oneliners not meant for sharing and the find/nullbyte solution has some added churn. Until I run into an error because of that and learn the hard way :) Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

you've hit xargs limit ?

```
xargs --show-limit
```

try :

- create a dummy `.tgz` file `tar czf xy_0_10000.tar.gz /hello/world`
- replace `-czf` by  `-Azf`

---

when xarg hit its limit, it will fork command, so command you ultimatly ran was

```
  tar czf xy_0_10000.tar.gz file1 file2 .... file666
  tar czf xy_0_10000.tar.gz file667 file668 ... file1203
  tar czf xy_0_10000.tar.gz file1024 ... file2000
```

as each tar overide previous one, you sould be getting only last `tar c` run.

Edit:

1) <s>according to `man tar` on unbuntu, `-a` and -r seems equivalent</s> append is done by (either)  `-A, --catenate, --concatenate`

2) `zip` (not `gzip`) can be used to add file, maybe a gzip option will do the trick. (use  `| xargs zip -qr xy_0_0000.zip` , this will result in a zip file, not a .tar.gz however)

3) to use @rsanchez's solution 
It is important to add option to tar in a proper way, try

```
ls | sort -n -k1.4,1.9 | head -n10000 |tar -czf xy_0_10000.tar.gz -T -
```

where 
 - `-T -` mean use option `-T` and use `-` as argument to `-T` (you could have generate a list of file in `/tmp/foo.lst` , then use `-T /tmp/foo.lst` )

Comment: could a (=add) instead of c (=create/overwrite) work around that limitation?

Comment: @OlivierDulac (**Warning: This is a pure guess**) It probably won't solve since tar can't create empty files. You **may** compress an empty folder first and use `a (add)` to add the files to the tar file. Then, you can open the tar and remove the folder (using 7zip or something)

Comment: @ismaelmiguel: I m pretty sure it will happily create the file. if not, just : `touch xy_0_10000.tar.gz && { _the full command here_ ; }`

Comment: @OlivierDulac That will be an invalid `.gz` file.

Comment: All the manpages I see from http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man1/tar.1.html (15.04) back to precise (12.04) have `-r` append but `-a` auto-compress which is not equivalent. And `-rz` doesn't work: `zip` can add to an existing archive because the directory is not compressed, but `tar` with compression compresses the metatdata along with the data. You can `tar -r` piecewise into an *uncompressed* archive and then gzip the result. Or ...

Comment: ... You can increase the amount `xargs` will do in one "chunk" with `-s num`; here `-s 200000` should be plenty. (There is some OS limit and I don't know what it is for Ubuntu, but I'd be surprised if 200k is too much.) Or just use `tar -T` as @rsanchez said.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - do you happen to have a complete working example with `xargs -s200000`? because when I execute `ls | sort -n -k1.4,1.9 | head -n10000 | xargs -s200000 tar -czf xy_0_10000.tar.gz`, it seems to try to compress the contents of the files  and fails with `<line_of_content> Cannot stat: No such file or directory`. Am I using it wrong?

Comment: @Archemar - have tries your advice but seem to be doing it wrong. Mind to take a look at the edit?

Comment: @Archemar ah, I have been using it wrong :) Have tried it as you advised, only to encounter a different error - the file names seem not to reach tar for some reason. Please see the edit.

Comment: why `--null` ? you are not sending null separated string.

Comment: @Archemar - not intended for real use, only to test whether the output of `head` reaches `tar`, the `T option requires an argument` error made me a bit paranoid :) still not sure how to get around it

Comment: @kostja For test case I just created a directory and 10k files using your name pattern and did `ls | xargs -s200000 tar -czf outfile.gz`. The only thing I can think of is a race condition between the `ls` and creating the outputfile -- or replacing it you do repeated attempts and a prior one is still there. Maybe try putting the output in another directory like `~/output` or `/tmp/output`. (Although getting the `-T-` approach to work is probably more useful.)

Answer (score 12):

There's no need for `xargs`. If you directly give `tar` the `-T -` option it will [read the filenames](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_48.html) from standard input.

For instance:

```
... | tar -T - -czf xy_0_10000.tar.gz
```

Comment: I seem to be using the option incorrectly, cannot get it to work with the pipe. Have tried `...| tar Tczf xy_...`, `...| tar Tcz -f xy_...` `...| tar -czf xy_... -T ` and several other permutations, but am getting only `tar: You must specify one of the '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or '--test-label' options`, `tar: -f: Cannot stat: No such file or directory` if using `-f` separately from other options and `tar: option requires an argument -- 'T'`. Could you please add a usage example?

Comment: @kostja example added.

Comment: Many thanks, rsanchez. Not sure why the variant with `-T -` at the end of the `tar` option list did not work, but your example did. Unfortunately, my question actually had two parts - the source of the error and a possible improvement. While you aced the latter, Archemar excelled at the former and almost had the latter right. I am not sure which of your answers to accept since they both were obviously helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I want to complement the two other answers with a *zsh* solution, which neither *parses ls*, nor needs *xargs*. However, I am not sure right now, if it suffers also from the limitation of the command line length.

1. Define a function which generates your desired sorting key by modifying `$REPLY`.

   ```
   sortkey() { REPLY=${REPLY[4,9]} }
   ```

   This is equivalent to your `sort -n -k1.4,1.9`
2. Generate an array `$files` with the filenames sorted with the above function:

   ```
   files=(*(o+sortkey))
   ```

   This is equivalent to `ls | sort -n -k1.4,1.9`
3. Return the first 10 000 files with

   ```
   ${files[0,9999]}
   ```

   This is equivalent to `ls | sort -n -k1.4,1.9 | head -n10000`

So, all in all this should do the trick:

```
sortkey() { REPLY=${REPLY[4,9]} }
files=(*(o+sortkey))
tar -czf xy_0_10000.tar.gz ${files[0,9999]}
```